# What is the intuition behind the measure of separation used in LDA?

Tags: self-study, pca, data-visualization, feature-selection

Whenever I've been taught Linear Discriminant Analysis I've seen the formula $\text{separation} = \frac{V_B}{V_W}$ where $V_B$ is the between-groups variance and $V_W$ is the within-groups variance.

However, I've never seen any justification for this. Even in the two class cases, what does the ratio of what are essentially means and variances tell me anything about how well a certain feature separates data in comparison with other features?

Comment: Consider the cases $V_B = 0$ and $V_B \gg V_W$.

Comment: Have you consulted classic textbooks such as Duda & Hart? I believe the authors justify this form pretty well.